# Where can I find older kernel documentation?

Tags: linux, kernel, kernel-parameters

I am trying to find kernel parameters documentation for v3.10 on the internet. I was able to find the latest version here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html back to v4.10. Is there a local copy of this documentation in my linux distro?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.10/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt?

Comment: @muru of course, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An effective while stealthy way is changing the `URL` directly. For example, if you want the kernel doc of `v5.18`, you can go to [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.18/): `https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.18/`

A list of different kernel documentation is easily to find [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html): `https://www.kernel.org/doc/html`

You can find the kernel parameters guide by appending `/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html` to the `URL` or by clicking the menus in the main page accordingly.

Comment: The OP is obviously aware of that since they mention only versions going back to 4.10 are available there while they're looking for v3.10

Answer (score 0):

The `Documentation` folder is part of the Linux kernel source code. It's now in `rst` (reStructured Text) format which is best read after conversion to `info` or `HTML` (using `sphinx`, see `make dochelp` at the toplevel of the source tree) but used to be in plain text.

Some Linux distributions make that part of the source code available in a `linux-doc` package or similar (on Debian and derivatives, it's extracted into `/usr/share/doc/linux-doc` though in raw `rst` format). Similarly, they supply the headers part in a `linux-header` package and in any case the whole thing in a source package (on Debian, use `apt source`).

You can also download source tarballs for any kernel version from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/, or browse the whole source code history from https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/ or mirrors such as https://github.com/torvalds/linux, and the `Documentation` part for each version at https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation?h=v3.10 or https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/v3.10/Documentation.

For versions prior to 2.6.11, go to https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/history/history.git